# Dynamic window size and buttons

Tags: java, layout, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a JPanel and i am creating JButtons dynamically on runtime. I want the JPanel size to be adjusted dynamically according to the number of JButtons added to it. What layout should i use ? And my JPanel will be added to the JFrame so can anyone explain what do i have to do to establish what I am trying to do ?

EDIT
After a bit of research I am using the following layout
`mode.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0, 1, 1));` 
Here `mode` is the JPanel. Now if i have just 2 JButtons added to the JPanel the buttons will be displayed one below the other which is fine. But I am getting extra space at the bottom of those 2 buttons. If I have 15 buttons I am getting 5 rows and 3 columns which is again fine but the window size is small I and I have to resize the window manually on runtime for displaying the buttons fully.

Specific Question: How to manage the window size on the above dynamic buttons scenario ?

Comment: `What layout should i use ?` -- I don't know. At least for me your description of what you're trying to do is too broad and vague to give a specific recommendation. Most all of the layouts will adjust size to the components, so what to use will depend on what look you're trying to achieve. If you need more help, please edit your post and tell us more.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: check my edit!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic code for adding components dynamically is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
```

Update:

You can use the following to get the Window that needs to be packed:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```

Comment: Then do a pack() on the frame after adding the buttons.

Comment: if i do pack() i am getting dynamic window size but the problem is the buttons are also packed and they are too small. I want it to be nice and big as this is touch screen application. so how to pack without affecting the button size ?